# Modulus.io NodeJS deployment

Tags: node.js, express, modulus.io

I'm trying to deploy my app to Modulus. I have set the environment variables:

- NODE_ENV = production
- MODULUSURL = mongodb://user:pw@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Ub7ehyqa
- PORT = 8080

When I deploy the app I'm receiving the following error:

> /mnt/data/1/server/api/user/index.js:10 router.get('/',
>   controller.index);
>          ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
>       at Object. (/mnt/data/1/server/api/user/index.js:10:8)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at module.exports (/mnt/data/1/server/routes.js:12:25)
>       at Object. (/mnt/data/1/server/app.js:24:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

It appears the MongoDB connection is established, so I've ruled that out as the issue. Also, this is not occurring in my local/dev environment. Is there a chance, when deploying to a production server (like Mondulus) I would need to update the paths to such components like express?

Comment: Currently running node 0.10.0. Was running express 3.3.4. Changed to ~4.0.0 and now the app deploys without error. Now getting a "Not Found" error when viewing the URL.

Comment: Do you get something in the log when the "Not Found" error occurs?
Additionally: Does it work locally?

Comment: Yes, works locally just fine, I should've specified. I'm using the angular-fullstack version 2.0.12 and I'm starting to think it's how grunt is generating the /dist directory for deployment. Also, the logs say nothing that would indicate an issue when deploying. I get the nice 'App now running...' or whatever the success message displays from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `MONGO_URL` not `MODULUSURL` and obviously don't post publicly, but make sure your fill in the username and password in the `MONGO_URL`.